# Getting 404 error when trying to login using Angular 6 & Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

Getting a 40(x) error trying to implement spring boot authentication for an angular 6 login component. Already have a customer table in a MySQL database with a customers name and password.

Below are files I am working on to try figure out the problem. The last image is the error I am getting after I input user data from the customer table.

## Java Spring Boot Code

#### Customer Controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public boolean login(@RequestBody Customer user) {
        return
          user.getCname().equals("user") && user.getPassword().equals("password");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authToken = request.getHeader("Authorization")
          .substring("Basic".length()).trim();
        return () ->  new String(Base64.getDecoder()
          .decode(authToken)).split(":")[0];
    }

    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        System.out.println("Get all Customers...");

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(customers::add);

        return customers;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/customers/create")
    public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

        Customer _customer = repository.save(new Customer(customer.getCname(), customer.getAddress(), customer.getPhone(),customer.getPassword()));
        return _customer;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/customers/{cid}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("cid") long cid) {
        System.out.println("Delete Customer with CID = " + cid + "...");

        repository.deleteByCid(cid);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("Customer has been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/customers/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteAllCustomers() {
        System.out.println("Delete All Customers...");

        repository.deleteAll();

        return new ResponseEntity<>("All customers have been deleted!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "customers/cname/{cname}")
    public List<Customer> findByAge(@PathVariable String cname) {

        List<Customer> customers = repository.findByCname(cname);
        return customers;
    }

    @PutMapping("/customers/{cid}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@PathVariable("cid") long cid, @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        System.out.println("Update Customer with CID = " + cid + "...");

        Optional<Customer> customerData = repository.findByCid(cid);

        if (customerData.isPresent()) {
            Customer _customer = customerData.get();
            _customer.setCname(customer.getCname());
            _customer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
            _customer.setPhone(customer.getPhone());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.save(_customer), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Authentication

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthConfiguration 
  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
        auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user")
          .password("password")
          .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) 
      throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

## Angular 6 / Typescript code

#### Login Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    model: any = {};


    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', '');
    }

    login() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:4200/login';
        this.http.post<Observable<boolean>>(url, {
            userName: this.model.username,
            password: this.model.password
        }).subscribe(isValid => {
            if (isValid) {
                sessionStorage.setItem('token', btoa(this.model.username + ':' + this.model.password));
                this.router.navigate(['']);
            } else {
                alert('Authentication failed.');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Home Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    userName: string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:4200';

        const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        });

        const options = { headers: headers };
        this.http.post<Observable<Object>>(url, {}, options).
            subscribe(principal => {
                this.userName = principal['name'];
            },
            error => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    alert('Unauthorized');
                }
            }
        );
    }

    logout() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', '');
    }
    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
          console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        return throwError(
          'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
      }
}
```

## Error

[image: error]

Comment: You should copy your code here, and not use screen captures.

Comment: Looks like the login url might be `http://localhost:4200/api/login` -- can you try that? Because the `@RequestMapping` decorators chain, I think... also in general we encourage folks to post code snippets as text, not images. But you did a great job capturing useful screenshots :-)

Comment: sorry, i have updated post as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are trying to send request to `http://localhost:4200`. You run your frontend on this port, but your backend is running on the another one. Possibly it's 8080. Try to change port in the url in your LoginComponent to 8080.